# predict confidence intervals in glmer, errors

Tags: r, predict, lme4, mixed-models

I have the following logistic glmer model:

```
model <- glmer(cbind(species, round(totalSpecies)-species) ~ poly(year,2) + (1|referenceID) + (1|country), 
                  family = binomial(cloglog), data=huntAll, control=glmerControl(optimizer="bobyqa"))
```

I am trying to use predict(), and then plot the confidence intervals of the predicted values.

This is what I thought would work:

```
pframe <- data.frame(year = seq(1972,2014))

Pred1 <- predict(model,re.form=NA,newdata=pframe,type="response")

pframe$speciesLOGIT<- predict(model,re.form=NA, newdata=pframe)

mm <- model.matrix(terms(model),pframe)

pvar1 <- diag(mm %*% tcrossprod(vcov(model),mm))
cmult <- 1.96

pframe <- data.frame(
  pframe
  , plo = pframe$speciesLOGIT-cmult*sqrt(pvar1)
  , phi = pframe$speciesLOGIT+cmult*sqrt(pvar1)
)
```

And then for use with a plotting function:

```
CI <- data.frame(
  pframe
  , ci1 = plogis(pframe$plo)*100
  , ci2 = plogis(pframe$phi)*100
)
```

Then I just added the columns from CI using the polygon() function.

This code worked when I was recently running a linear mixed effects model using lmer in lme4. But when I try to use it in this logistic glmer, I get the following error when producing mm:

```
Error in model.frame.default(object, data, xlev = xlev) : 
 variable lengths differ (found for 'poly(year, 2)')
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In round(totalSpecies) - species :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
2: In cbind(species, round(totalSpecies) - species) :
  number of rows of result is not a multiple of vector length (arg 1)
```

I can't seem to get it to work.
Any thoughts?

Comment: I would have imagined that you would need values for the random effects variables if your intent was prediction.

Comment: Thanks 42, but I am not sure how to do this...

Comment: You don't know how to specify values of `referenceID` and `country` when creating `pframe'?